# Por que o limite diário é de 200 pontos e nas minhas realizações hoje tenho 235?

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Por que o limite diário é de 200 pontos e nas minhas realizações hoje tenho 235? Será que é algum bug?

Comment: Mas o 2349 mudou conforme o 235?

Comment: Não percebi... vou acompanhar amanhã para ver se consigo fazer 200 pontos e se há alteração na pontuação geral após os 200 pontos.

Comment: Então vou resumir o que aconteceu, você está contabilizando os pontos da aceitação em suas respostas, mas eles não contam (eu acho), somente os upvotes contam no limite. Você teve 5 aceitações nas ultimas 24 horas, cada uma lhe gera +15, `5 x 15 = 75`, se ganhou 235 então é `235 - 75 = 160`, ou seja 160 foram os upvotes e ainda estão dentro do limite diário.

Comment: OK. Acho que é isso então... vou tentar responder mais alguma coisa hoje para ver se a pontuação muda.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/31016/allan-andrade?tab=reputation Clique para expandir os nós da pontuação. Quando for "aceitação", não contabiliza para o cap de 200 pontos. Bonificação dada por usuários também não conta.

Comment: Muito obrigado mais uma vez, ficou claro agora: então os 15 pontos das respostas aceitas não estão sujeitas ao limite diário.

Comment: Isso mesmo Allan ;)